# TF10121 Error Visual Studio 2013

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I have a project in Team Foundation Server. Every Time I try to either check out and check files in I get the following error.

Team Foundation Error
TF10121: The patch is not found or not supported. Type or select a different path.

[image]

I am running from the web based Version of TFS and i am using Visual Studio 2013.

Any one any idea how to fix this pop up its not allowing me to check items in.

Comment: Does this error replicable when you are trying to checkout files which are not added to a solution but exist in source control? Also, is this issue replicable for all projects in your solution or is happening for specific projects?

Comment: It is replaceable for all projects in my solution it is not allowing me to check in anything at all. Any answer on this would be great.

Comment: @Inkey Did you try to open the solution and remove the project Melt.sln then re-add it? Also you can try to remove source control bindings and add the solution to source control again.

Comment: It appears that the solution may not reside in TFS, but the client and the solution binding thinks it is.  If you manually add the .SLN file to TFS (using source explorer) this may solve the issue.

Comment: First, please check that the solution is binded with TFS or not. You can check this by verify this by clicking File->Source Control->Add solution to source control. If you see add solution enabled then it means this solution is not added to source control. If it's disabled then solution is binded in TFS. In this case, there might be some issues with binding. You can fix this by doing unbind and bind again from File->Source Control ->Advanced->Change Source Control.

Comment: @MatijaGrcic There never was any file in the application called melt.sln

Comment: Any one able to help before the bounty closes?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your workspace mapping, to what disk path it is mapped. Quick way to do this is to fire up VS 2013, Open "Source Control Explorer" and navigate to the SLN file. Check if it provides a path or says "Not mapped" on top. If it is mapped, try clicking on the path's link and open it.

Comment: No matter what project i open i get this error. Even if i create a new project from scratch without adding it to TFS

Comment: Hang on. Is it reporting the same path (met.sln) for all projects? Or is the path that is not found = the solution you are working on (the one you are checking in/out) ? 

Another thing I would do is to check the list of "Pending Checkins" in your Team Explorer view. if you see Met.sln there, you will need to "Exclude" it manually (right-click and Exclude) and then check in. After you exclude, VS will not attempt to check that thing back in unless you do so manually.

Comment: Yes it is reporting the same path for all projects. I have excluded everything apart from  the new test project i created. When i run it i still get the same error. Even when i go into Source Control Explorer i get the error.

Comment: Try this. Open the "Developer Command Prompt" and type in "tf status >> SOME_TEMP_FOLDER\changes.txt". Now open this Changes.txt file and look for "Melt.sln". Do you see it?

Comment: Cannot find a folder called changes.txt